# How does this function change the value of a variable declared on the stack?

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, memory-address, vulkan

I am currently learning a bit of programming with the Vulkan API. This is how a typical call in that API goes. Don't worry about too much with the meaning if you are not familiar with it.

```
pickPhysicalDevices(){
    uint32_t deviceCount = 0;
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &deviceCount, nullptr);
}
```

Basically, the vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices function returns the count of physical devices available to the system and places that value into deviceCount. My question is since I declared deviceCount on the pickPhysicalDevices() function stack, why is vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices not causing a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is because `pickPhysicalDevices` explicitly allows `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` modify `deviceCount` variable by providing its pointer.

C++ offers multiple ways of letting a function modify a value inside another function's context - by passing a pointer or by passing a reference.

What you pass, a pointer or a reference, depends on the declaration of the function you call. If a function takes `uint32_t&` (with an ampersand) then you pass a variable without an ampersand, and the function receives a reference. If a function takes `uint32_t*` (with an asterisk) then you pass a pointer to the variable by using the address-of operator `&`.

Once you are inside the function that takes a pointer, you can write `*pointer = ...` to assign a new value to the variable to which the pointer is pointing. References, on the other hand, do not need an asterisk.

Try these two approaches in a simple program:

```
void by_ref(uint32_t& ref) {
    ref = 123; // No asterisk
}
void by_ptr(uint32_t* ptr) {
    *ptr = 456; // Note the asterisk
}
int main() {
    uint32_t a, b;
    by_ref(a);
    by_ptr(&b);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is this also true for C? I received a lot of the lower level education in C mostly and if I remember correctly, this would typically not be allowed, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @KhalidAkash C has no references, but whatever I said about pointers is entirely true in C as well. In fact, C++ pointers behave exactly the way C pointers do.

Comment: Right, I understand the reference part. The confusion I guess is just that I wasn't sure how another function was able to change a non-dynamically allocated part of memory. But according to another answer, child functions do have access to its parent's functions stack, or something akin to it?

I was taught that basically that accessing anything outside of your own stack, if its not in the heap, is a big no-no.

Comment: @KhalidAkash Stack of a parent is considered "inside" for the child, because the child's stack frame is above the frames of all its parents (hence, "the stack"). Once the child exits, its frame is deallocated, and any memory of that frame is off limits.

Comment: The program can change any part of memory that belongs to it (with exceptions - there can be "execute only" parts of memory (can be executed, but not read/written), "read only", and others. But in any case, the stack is always changing and is where local scope variables sit. Both the caller and callee are on the same thread and have the same access rights to the stack memory.

Comment: @Steve thank you for the clarification. Any particular place I can look at for these specifications (really interested to explore further)? Probably a google search away so nevermind.

Comment: @das C and C++ pointers are not quite exactly the same.  Aliasing rules in C++ and C are not the same.  However this information is actively harmful at Khalid's level of understanding, so I will not go on.

Comment: I realize the link I posted earlier isn't really good for this purpose. It says "Any thread can potentially access any object in the program", but it doesn't even mention the stack).

Answer (score 0):

The param deviceCount's address is pushed into the vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices's stack frame.

So, when you change the value of deviceCount in vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices, it'’s actually changing the vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices's own stack frame.

Comment: So what about when you return from vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices, that stack gets popped, right?

Comment: Since the param deviceCount is an address, when you change the value you are changing the memory that the address points to. When you return from vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices, the stack gets popped, but the memory still there, so that you can get the value from pickPhysicalDevices's stack.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit pedantic ... Both `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevice` and the parameter to the function (a pointer to `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevice`) are on the *same stack* (there is one stack per thread). They are in two different *stack frames*, which are adjacent in memory.

Comment: @Steve, when i said stack i mean the stack frame. Each function has its own stack frame on stack.

Comment: So vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices is changing a value in a different stack (because it has that memory address), but wouldn't this cause a seg-fault because I thought functions are only allowed to change variables values in their own stack? 

"The param deviceCount's address is pushed into the vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices's stack. ", does this sentence mean that the scope of vkEnumeratePhysicalDevice is the scope of pickPhysicalDevices, that doesn't sound right.

@Steve you are right, I mean stackframe when I mention that.

Comment: @KhalidAkash see my comment on dasblinkenlight's answer. The allowed types of access to memory isn't quite that granular.

Comment: Stack memory have some guards, you cannot change it as you like, however, the stack frame of the caller can be accessable. This book can clarify your question: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Book/book_sample_buffer.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can't *return* the address of a local variable because after a function returns its local variables go out of scope. Passing it as a *parameter* is fine, though, since the parent function's variables are in scope for the duration of the child function.